# How to disable/enable input when user select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.16, What I'm trying to achieve is to disable/enable input when user select dropdown.
[image]

eg. When user select 0, then disable the input.
When other options is selected, enable the input.

please check the code below.

```
 { "targets": [OPTIONS], "orderable": false,
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                var optionsCombo ='<select class="form-control OPTIONS_DATA" name="OPTIONS_DATA" style="width: 150px;"> ';
        
                for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                    optionsCombo += `<option value='${data[i].options_code}' >${data[i].options_desc}</option>`;
                }
                optionsCombo += '</select>';
                return optionsCombo ;
       } 
},
{ "targets": [DETAILS], "orderable": false,
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return `<input class="form-control DETAILS" name="DETAILS" type="number" maxlength="2" style="" value = ${data}>`;
              } 
            }
```

rendered HTML code:

```
<select class="form-control OPTIONS_DATA options0" name="OPTIONS_DATA" style="width: 150px;"> 
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
```

```
<input class="form-control DETAILS detailsRow0" name="DETAILS" " type="number" maxlength="2" >
```

now I'm able to disable the input by putting the following code in createdRow event.

```
$(row).find('input').attr('readonly', 'true');
```

I also follow the solution posted on [this link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30584/select-dropdown-in-table-cell-not-firing) but it doesn't work for me.

I also use this function. It works when I put it on chrome console but when I put it inside js file, I'm not able to disable/enable the input.

```
 $('#example select.form-control.OPTIONS.options0').change(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == 1) {
                $('#example input.detailsRow0').prop( "disabled", false );
        } else {       
        $('#example input.detailsRow0').prop( "disabled", true );
        }
    });
```

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: Try providing some code of what you have done until now.

Comment: The example in the link also shows how to add a `change` event listener to a dropdown, which is exactly what you need here. "Doesn't work for me" is a useless problem description, you need to mention error messages, the actual vs. expected behavior, etc.

Comment: You can try this: `$(document).on('change','.OPTIONS_DATA',function() { var row = $(this).closest("tr"); $(row).find('input').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == 0);})`

Comment: the question is edited. Thanks!

Comment: @SRN In your jquery example that you just added, When is the 2 classes (`OPTIONS`&`options0`) added to your select?

Comment: @SRN Please take the rendered html code of the table and paste it into your question, then we can give you an good answer.

Comment: the 2 classes is added by createdRow event using this code.                                                      
                    $('td:eq(4) select', row).addClass('options'+index);
                    $('td:eq(5) input', row).addClass('detailsRow'+index);

Answer (score 0):

Just by the image posted on OP, I saw why there might be difficulty. Tags that are in table cells are hard to grasp in the beginning. Normally, in a layout, when traversing the DOM it's easy because nested tags where accessible and most referencing originated from `document`.

Tables on the otherhand, are clusterred and each individual cell and it's contents are isolated because HTML tables are heavily row oriented -- `<tr>` are added/removed, they hold all of the cells in order, etc. yet they are invisible.

Here are some things to keep in mind:

- 99% of the time form controls require user interaction.

  - Consider a form event (ex. input, change, submit, reset, etc)
  - The origin tag (ie the element the user interacted with like clicked, changed, hovered over, etc) can be referenced using `event.target` or `this` (jQuery `$(this)`) within the event handler (ie the function used when a watched event triggers.)
  - If your `e.target` or `this` is in a table cell, then it's more than likely you want to access another tag that's in the same row. Start your traversal from `this`:

    - `this` goes up to the cell it's in

      ```
       <td>
        <select> // $(this).parent('td')
       </td>
      ```
    - Now think from the cell's perspective it needs to go to the next cell and down into the cell to `.find()` the input.

      ```
            
      <td></td>  <td>
                  <input>  // .next('td').find('input');
                 </td>
      ```

```js
$('select').on('change', switchFields);

function switchFields(e) {
  const input = $(this).parent('td').next('td').find('input');

  if ($(this).val() === "0") {
    input.prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    input.prop('disabled', false);
  }
};
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td><select>
          <option default></option>
          <option value=0>OFF</option>
          <option value=1>ON</option>
         </select></td><td><input></td></tr>
<tr><td><select>
          <option default></option>
          <option value=0>OFF</option>
          <option value=1>ON</option>
         </select></td><td><input></td></tr>
<tr><td><select>
          <option default></option>
          <option value=0>OFF</option>
          <option value=1>ON</option>
         </select></td><td><input></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```